# How do you set the editor type for a label in a wxPython PropertyGrid?

Tags: python, wxpython

I figured out how to set the labels on a wxPython PropertyGrid as editable with `pg.MakeColumnsEditable(0)`, but this only allows editing with a `textctrl`.  Is there a way to set the editor on the label of a property grid element like we can on the value?  By label I mean the first column of the property grid, and value refers to the second column.

In the following MWE, I setup a property grid, add two string properties, and then an Enum property.  I then set the labels to be editable with the command above.  What I would really like is the ability to chose labels from a list of choices, like the EnumProperty does with its value.  While the wxPython demo shows several examples of how to create custom editors for values on Property Grids, there are no examples demonstrating how to set a custom editor on a label.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible, and if so, how it is done?

Minimal Working Example:

```py
import wx
import wx.propgrid as wxpg

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200,100))
        pg = wxpg.PropertyGrid(self)
        pg.Append(wxpg.StringProperty('A', value='1'))
        pg.Append(wxpg.StringProperty('B', value='2'))
        pg.Append(wxpg.EnumProperty('Select', 'Select', ['1', '2', '3']))
        pg.MakeColumnEditable(0)
        self.Show(True)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyFrame(None, 'Property Grid MWE')
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use an EnumProperty in place of the StringProperty for those? You'd get the default EnumEditor that way.  Alternatively, set `EditorDescriptor` for the property and point at the EnumEditor.

Comment: or the  MultiChoiceProperty (see docs)[https://www.wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.propgrid.PGProperty.html]?
        pg.Append(wxpg.MultiChoiceProperty('B', 'X', ['x', 'y', 'z'], value=['x']))

Comment: Each property that is appended has a label (first columns of grid) and a value (second column of grid).  The EnumProperty allows you to select from a list of options for the value (second column of the grid), but I need to be able to select from a list of options for the label (first column of the grid).  That is fundamentally what this question is asking, but I have probably not worded it very well.